# How to reload helpers on rails mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails mountable engine:

```
config.to_prepare do
  # works fine, and reload automatically in development
  ApplicationController.helper :application

  # works fine, but doesn't reload. After restart server, it works.
  ApplicationController.helper Rails.application.helpers
```

It looks like fine when arg is symbol or string. But it doesn't work when arg is a module like `Rails.application.helpers`.

Or is there a good way to get all helpers like `[:application, :users]` from `Rails.application.helpers`.

Rails: 4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can configure autoload_paths of the engine.

lib/my_engine/engine.rb

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    ...
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Engine.root.join('app', 'helpers')]
  end
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html

Comment: I have already tried autoload_paths, but it doesn't work. And I want to reload main app helpers.

Answer (score -1):

for people using rails 6, you might want to try using the classic autoloader instead of zeitwerk

```rb
config.autoloader = :classic
```